# Recursive algorithm substitution?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I'm working through a [problem set](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/assignments/ps1.pdf) through MIT's OpenCourseWare and am having some trouble with recurrences.

The problem is 1-2d:

> Give asymptotic upper and lower bounds for $T(n)$ in each of the
>   following recurrences. Assume that $T(n)$ is constant for $n \leq 10$.
>   Make your bounds as tight as possible, and justify your answers.
>
> - $T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \Theta(\lg\lg n)$

The solution states:

> **Change of variables:** Let $m = \lg n$.  Recurrence becomes $S(m) = S(m/2) + \Theta (\lg m)$. Case 2 of Master Theorem applies, so $T(n) = \Theta((\lg\lg n)^2)$.

How does the given substitution lead to the new recurrence relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $m = \lg n$, then $n = 2^m$. So $T(2^m) = T(2^{m/2}) + \Theta(\log m)$. Now set $S(m) = T(2^m)$, which means $S(m/2) = T(2^{m/2})$.